# mongodb lost collections catalog

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, wiredtiger

We are using MongoDB 3.0.4, in standalone mode, with wiredTiger, Windows Server 2008 x64.
We have a situation where MongoDB lost the "catalog" of collections (I think).

We use this database in a JavaEE application, inside Wildfly 8.2.0.Final.
The mongo-java-driver version is 3.0.0.

Looking in the folders all the collections files exists (collection-*.wt) and index files too, but in the repair, showCollections, and other commands, the database found just 2 collections (we have almost 20).
These 2 collections were "recreated" by the application when the service was restarted.

In MongoDB logs, we found just the shutdown and start logs. In the logs we don´t found any error log.

Someone have any idea of what happened here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have almost sure that the MongoDB/WiredTiger catalog was corrupted by a unexpected shutdown of the machine. (Looking in the MongoDB and Windows logs there's evidences about that.)

Searching for a way out in the web, I found [this bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-18640) and [this improvement](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19815) that probably will fix the this problem, or maybe offer a way to recover the data if happens again.

After read the bug/improvement I think that today there's no way to recover my data.
Unfortunately I will need to restore a backup and start from there.